# Looking for a book about the beginning of genetic engineering in the near future

Tags: story-identification, novel, mutant, genetic-engineering, genetics

A book I read in the mid 2000's was set in the near future, and involved the beginning of human genetic manipulation.

Two sides of the USA emerged: the non-mutated and the mutated. The mutated were lead by a charismatic genius, and they developed wings, claws, and other animal-like parts. This change tore the country apart. I don't remember many details other than that.